# File.Move = path?

Tags: c#

Good morning, I should solve this problem.
file.move locates a local path on my pc.
if I had to move it to another pc this would not work because the paths are different.
there is a method for entering a unique path:
File.move ("C: \ Desktop \ myfile", "C: \ Desktop \ myfolder \ myfile")
thanks for help

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    label2.Text = "Download in corso";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.homebrewsrv.altervista.org/OresteTool/trucchi/10%20in%201%20Arcade%20Collection%20EUR.rar"), desktop + "/ " + "10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    File.Move("C: \\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\ 10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar", "C: \\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza\\10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C.

Comment: That looks like C#. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your error message is but i do notice some errors.

The first error is this line:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza");
```

If you start a string with @ you are telling it not to escape your characters, so you should change this to one of the following:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza");
```

or

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\orest\Desktop\zazza");
```

Then you have an unnecessary sleep but i guess you know that..

```
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Then there is this line which have some whitespaces in the incorrect places, change this to:

```
File.Move("C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar", "C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza\\10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");
```

Then it should work, or you could skip the escaping (\) and just use one but then you need the @ sign in the beginning.

But.... you are using DownloadFileAsync so you need to handle this correctly, if you dont know what that is i suggest you change your example to the following:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    label2.Text = "Download in corso";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.homebrewsrv.altervista.org/OresteTool/trucchi/10%20in%201%20Arcade%20Collection%20EUR.rar", desktop + "/ " + "10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza");
    File.Move("C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar", "C:\\Users\\orest\\Desktop\\zazza\\10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");
}
```

This is not async but you should read up on that. Also you could download directly to your zazza directory instead of moving there later on but again i am guessing there is some reason for this.

If this dont work, please provide an error message and tell us exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

this script works only locally on my PC.
if you want to import this feature on another pc will not work because probably the other pc will not be called  `"C: \\ Users \\ orest \\ Desktop \\"  etc ..`

basically if the other pc is called `"C: \\ Users \\ mypc \\ Desktop \\" etc..ecc.`  this does not work.

it would serve a unique path of the type:

```
File.Move ("C: \\ Desktop \\ 10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar", "C: \\ Desktop \\ zazza \\ 10 in 1 Arcade Collection EUR.rar");
```

I hope to have explained to you correctly, forgive my bad c #, you will notice that they are the first weapons.